# Android error, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

My app is crashing every time, I couldn't find any solution for the issue.

The code is:

```
package com.example.juan.sem4;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Registrarse extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText txtNom, txtCor, txtPas;
    Button btnRegistrarse;

    BD_Usuarios bd=new BD_Usuarios(this,"BD1",null,1);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registrarse);

        txtNom=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtRegNom);
        txtCor=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtRegCor);
        txtPas=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPas);
        btnRegistrarse=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRegistrarse);

        btnRegistrarse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bd.abrir();
                bd.registrarUsu(txtNom.getText().toString(),txtCor.getText().toString(),txtPas.getText().toString());
                bd.cerrar();

                txtCor.setText("");
                txtNom.setText("");
                txtPas.setText("");
                txtNom.findFocus();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Se registro con exito",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();


            }
        });

    }
}
```

The LOGCAT shows the following problem:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                         at com.example.juan.sem4.Registrarse$1.onClick(Registrarse.java:32)
                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

It seems that the issue is on the line 32 which is:

> bd.registrarUsu(txtNom.getText().toString(),txtCor.getText().toString(),txtPas.getText().toString());

But honestly I can't see the problem in it.

Comment: The problem means that one of your text boxes doesn't exist, Just be sure that all text boxes you use are exists.

Comment: Share with us the xml file, maybe you are missing a tag.

Comment: You are doing to much in one line of code. You should break it up using variables to store each string value.

Comment: @user7790438 I checked it again but all text boxes exist. Actually, this is part of my class of last saturday. My professor made the same code without any issues in his computer. But I am having this problem with the same code... I still can't solve it.